# Google Spreadsheet SUMIF SUM

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I need help. The employee has 10 hours per year at SICK, which are paid as working hours. I need help with formula. Example and more info are here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OfrNwIxavO89qN0HSZ6x_3hVi1MS1orFNv2VOd0OMx0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I update your file have your try doing like this =if($D$7<10;sum(B2:C2);if(D$7>10;sum(B2:D2);0))

Comment: There is still some mistake. The results should also be as in column H.

Comment: i revised the formula it getting to the first 3 rows=if($D$7<10;sum(B2:D2);if(D$7>10;sum(B2:D2);0))

Comment: what triggers for apr of 2hrs and which cells reference?

Answer (score 0):

Try dividing the problem into smaller parts, like this:

cumulative sick hours: `=sum(D$2:D2)`

paid sick hours: `=if( E2 < D$8; D2; max(0; D$8 - n(E1)) )`

total: `=sum(B2:C2; F2)`

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OfrNwIxavO89qN0HSZ6x_3hVi1MS1orFNv2VOd0OMx0/edit#gid=1889133198) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Working! Perfect. Thank you.